# Mongoid create empty collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have i snip code to create empty collection in MongoDB

```
session = Moped::Session.new([ '127.0.0.1:27017' ])
  database = Moped::Database.new(session, 'test_database')
  collection = Moped::Collection.new(database,'test_collection')
```

but it is not working. how can i make it works? thanks

I am using Ruby on Rails with Mongoid

Comment: are you getting any error? if yes, please post that here.

Answer (score 2):

As near as I can tell there's nothing in the Moped interface like the native [`createCollection`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/) command. Mongoid and Moped generally create collections when you try to insert data into them or create an index on them.

However, you can call `createCollection` directly if you so desire using the [`command`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/moped/Moped/Database:command) method:

```
database.command(:eval => 'db.createCollection("test_collection")')
```